# dapper linq Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, linq, dapper

I have simple customer table that has 4 records, and only one has email

```
public string Username { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }

............

var data = cn.Query<Customer>("select * from customer");

var aaa= data.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Email.ToLower() == "admin@yourstore.com"); >> ok
var bbb= data.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Email.ToLower() == "kjhkh");
```

since other items have `email = null`, so it gets:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Why it's that tricky to use linq with Dapper, am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Off-topic, but important: you should do `cn.Query<Customer>("select * from customer").ToList();`. Currently, you're re-executing the query with each `FirstOrDefault` statement (probably not a big deal with 4 records, but it's about correct patterns).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`string.Equals()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4411bks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with a [`StringComparison`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) type:

```
var a = data.FirstOrDefault(f => string.Equals(f.Email, "test@test.com", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

This works since `Equals()` won't throw a null-reference exception when either one of the arguments is `null`. `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` indicates that the comparison is case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

This would get rid of your null reference exceptions:

```
var aaa= data.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Email != null && f.Email.ToLower() == "admin@yourstore.com");
var bbb= data.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Email != null && f.Email.ToLower() == "kjhkh");
```